# WebStorm disables syntax highlight for special file name?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

WebStorm disables syntax highlight for a special filename? I can not find the rule of that behavior.

The file named `AlbumDetail.js` 's syntax highlight seems to be disabled and the file named `CupDetai.js` 's syntax highlight is enabled.

I want to use AlbumDetail as a file name.

**Disabled**

[image: Disabled]

**Enabled**

[image: Enabled]

**Updated: A whole image of editor**

`AlbumDetail.js` is focused.

[image]

Comment: With `AlbumDetail.js` window focused, click on the Hector icon on the bottom right of the IDE. Where is the slider?

Comment: Please open Preferences | Editor | File Types and check that this file name is not listed under Ignored files or folders or not associates with the wrong file type.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Where is the Hector icon? I touched buttons on the right bottom corners and I couldn't find the settings.

There are no AlbumDetail.js in Preferences | Editor | File Types.

Comment: you can try using *Code | Configure Current File Analysis* main menu item instead. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html